How to handle SharePoint 2,000 lists and libraries combined per site limit for large number of lists/libraires?
I have more than 300K+ customers. Each customer has many documents (no limit, but on average 2500 documents).
I plan to create many sites. Each site contains 2000 document libraries for each 2000 customers. so "site1" contains 2000 libraries for first 2000 customers. I need to create and maintain more than 150 sites. Is it a good design?
Any other better way to handle the situation?

If the library fulfils a single Customer's need, then the design looks sound.
Have you considered permissions? Do you plan on breaking permission inheritance for libraries?
Mind you, 2,000 lists and libraries combined per site collection is the limit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits
So do not put EXACTLY 2000 Customer libraries in each site. Go for about 1970.
How are you going to keep track which Customer library is which site?
You mention also that there is "no limit" for Customer documents. Have you considered storage management? Each site has by default 100GB - you may need to raise it.
Have you considered structuring/viewing views for large number of documents? You can have up to 30 mln documents but they won't perform well or open at all if you throw them all into one view.

Thanks @grisha. My customer ID is a sequence/identity (integer). For example, for customer 300001, 300001/1500 = 200 (considering 1500 libraries per site), so the customer will be in "site200".  I don't plan on breaking permission inheritance.
